# ERC1155 minter function

Tags: solidity, contract-design

im working on a ERC1155 token.
as you may know openzeppelin has a presetMinter for it, but i want to mint my token with more complex things.

i see 3 methods to do it:

1- without using presetMinter from openzeppelin. right a minter funtion by myself in MyToken.sol

2- import presetMinter from openzeppelin to MyToken.sol and override that minter funtion with my custom one in MyToken.sol

3- import presetMinter from openzeppelin to MyToken.sol and declare a MyMint function that do all the things and passes the variables to presetMinter from openzeppelin. and try to call MyMint funtion for minting my token.

which is the best method? i mean which is more standard to do?
any other comments for doing this would be appreciated!